# Present value of profits

Tags: interest-rate

In Shapiro, C. (1983). Premiums for High Quality Products as Returns to Reputations. The Quarterly Journal of Economics, 98(4), 659. doi:10.2307/1881782, they assume the one-period interest rate is $r=\exp(iT) - 1$. $p(q)$ and $c(q)$ are the price and cost of producing a unit good of quality $q$.

They write on page 8:

> The alternative strategy of maintaining quality forever yields
> a constant flow of "profits" of $p(q) - c(q)$, which has a present value of $(p(q) - c(q))(1 + r)/r$

I am very confused as I would think the present value of profits would be $\frac{p(q) - c(q)}{1+r}$

Can someone explain me why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually it was easy: they summed the revenue over time.

$\sum_{i\ge0} \frac1{(1+r)^i} = \frac{1}{1 - \frac{1}{1+r}} = \frac{1+r}r$